# Is there Islamic scriptural justification for Islamic rulers breaking idols and demolishing temples of other religions?

Tags: shirk, jihad, other-religions, hindu

This is something that happened in India.

They demolished temples and idols of Hindus (1)in their own kingdoms and (2)in the Hindu kingdoms they were at war with.

Does either of the above cases have scriptural justification in Islam? Does Islam encourage Muslims and/or Muslim rulers to destroy idols and places of worship of other religions?

Also, in the above case, are these Muslim rulers considered to be committing Jihad(Holy War)?

Note:The more specific verses are about breaking idols, the better.

Comment: @UmH I think you should change it to there is already an answer instead of treating it as a duplicate question since I aksed for in their own kingdom and also at kingdoms they are at war with.

Comment: The answer covers both of these. It is a duplicate.

Comment: @UmH The answer, yes, but the question doesn't. Therefore you should select "The question already has an answer here:" not "Similar Question"

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403448/this-question-already-has-answers-here-vs-this-question-already-exists

Comment: I don't think that functionality exists on this SE site.

Comment: A duplicate is when the answer already exists this is explicitly mentioned in the corresponding link in [help].